# LibGit2Sharp and TFS Git repository

Tags: git, tfs, libgit2sharp

I have cloned:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp

which as I understand is the git client used in TFS 2015. I am trying to run the test:

```
   public void CanCloneFromBBWithCredentials(string url, string user, string pass, bool secure)
```

In:

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CloneFixture.cs

Where I have updated it to use a Git repository I have in TFS:

```
    [Theory]
    //[InlineData("https://libgit2@bitbucket.org/libgit2/testgitrepository.git", "libgit3", "libgit3", true)]

    [InlineData("http://tfs/tfs/collection/project/_git/MyRepo", "myUser", "myPass", false)]
   // [InlineData("http://tfs/tfs/collection/project/_git/MyRepo", "myUser", "myPass", true)]

        public void CanCloneFromBBWithCredentials(string url, string user, string pass, bool secure)
        {
            var scd = BuildSelfCleaningDirectory();

            string clonedRepoPath = Repository.Clone(url, scd.DirectoryPath, new CloneOptions()
            {
                CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => CreateUsernamePasswordCredentials (user, pass, secure)
            });

            using (var repo = new Repository(clonedRepoPath))
```

But when I run the test I get the following exception:

```
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result) in c:\tmp\Repos\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:line 160
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.ZeroResult(Int32 result) in c:\tmp\Repos\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Ensure.cs:line 178
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts) in c:\tmp\Repos\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Core\Proxy.cs:line 328
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options) in c:\tmp\Repos\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp\Repository.cs:line 694
   at LibGit2Sharp.Tests.CloneFixture.CanCloneFromBBWithCredentials(String url, String user, String pass, Boolean secure) in c:\tmp\Repos\libgit2sharp\LibGit2Sharp.Tests\CloneFixture.cs:line 227
```

I have verified that I can use the userName and password provided above to clone the repository from command line using: https://git-scm.com/

Any ideas on how to run libgit2sharp tests against a TFS 2015 Git repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultCredentials` type is what you're after as TFS git protocol doesn't rely on username and password for authentication.

As stated by the **[xml documentation](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/a026f5d84e35f1df94bc3f30503429ef8a216209/LibGit2Sharp/DefaultCredentials.cs#L6-L9)**, it's *"A credential object that will provide the "default" credentials (logged-in user information) via NTLM or SPNEGO authentication."*

Settings the `CloneOptions.CredentialsProvider` to the following should do the trick

```
CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new DefaultCredentials()
```